# QTableWidget doesn't show values

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I am trying to insert a data set into a QTableWidget using PyQt. However, when I use `tableWidget.setItem()` my IDE crashes.

```
        usuarios = db.child("operacoes").get()
        line = 0
        for usuario in usuarios.each():
            dados = list(usuario.val().values())
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(line, 0, QTableWidgetItem(dados[0]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(line, 1, QTableWidgetItem(dados[1]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(line, 2, QTableWidgetItem(dados[2]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(line, 3, QTableWidgetItem(dados[3]))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(line, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(dados[4])))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(line, 5, QTableWidgetItem(str(dados[5])))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(line, 6, QTableWidgetItem(str(dados[6])))
            line = line + 1
```

The data is retrieved from Firebase and stored in a vector. I'm trying to use the same loop that I use to retrieve the data from firebase to fill the table. However,  when I execute this code my QTableWidget is blank.

My `dados` vector has the following values:

```
dados[0] = "01/01/2000"
dados[1] = "JPY"
dados[2] = "teste"
dados[3] = "BRL"
dados[4] = 1.40
dados[5] = 14.00
dados[6] = 100
```

My table is designed like this using QtDesigner:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please include the error you get (if any). Check if 'dados' contains valid values.

Comment: @AndrewQ I got no error messages and `dados` contain valid values (i've printed on console).

Comment: @AndrewQ I've edited the original question with the `dados` values.

Comment: Did you create the QTableWidget with the right number of rows and columns? What you mean with "my IDE crashes"? Your program or i.e. PyCharm?

Comment: @AndrewQ The program stops running and I have to close it in the IDE.

Comment: @AndrewQ, I've added an image of my `QTableWidget`

Comment: I think that you should add a `self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(usuarios))` before the for.

Comment: I've changed to `self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(list(usuarios.val().values())))` then it worked. When I used `self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(usuarios))` gives me an error telling that `PyreBase response has no len`. Thanks for the help! You can post it as an answer to me assign it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the docs of `QTableWidget`, before adding `QTableWidgetItems` into cells you must declare the size of the `QTableWidget` (rows and columns). This can be done at the creation of the table object (in the constructor), or changing the size of the table **before** inserting items.
In your case, you probably have created a table with a size of 1 row x 7 columns, so you must resize the table before inserting the items.
This can be achieved adding

```
usuarios = db.child("operacoes").get()
line = 0
self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(list(usuarios.val().values())))
for usuario in usuarios.each():
    dados = list(usuario.val().values())
    self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(line, 0, QTableWidgetItem(dados[0]))
    ....
```